# Using GoogleMLKit 0.61.0 thru CocoaPods is downgrading Firebase libs to 6.20.0

Tags: ios, firebase, google-mlkit

Using **GoogleMLKit 0.61.0** thru CocoaPods is downgrading Google Firebase libs from the latest one defined in my project to older version detailed below

```
before MLKit - Firebase/Analytics (6.27.0)
after MLKit  - Firebase/Analytics (6.20.0)

before MLKit - Firebase/Core (6.27.0):
after MLKit  - Firebase/Core (6.20.0):

before MLKit  - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
before MLKit  - FirebaseCore (6.8.0):
before MLKit  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.3)
after MLKit   - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
after MLKit   - FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.5.0)
after MLKit   - FirebaseCore (6.6.4):
after MLKit   - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.2)
after MLKit   - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
```

My podfile:

```
...
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning', '= 0.61.0'. //Latest GoogleMLKit version
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition', '= 0.61.0'
...
```

As per the [changelog](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/release-notes#android_1600_ios_0600) it doesn't have any dependency on Firebase, but still when I try to use that it is updating the firebase as well.
And we cannot use the older Firebase version because we faced many issues and crashes there

```
This is the first release of ML Kit as a standalone SDK, independent from Firebase.
This SDK offers all the on-device APIs that were previously offered through the ML Kit for Firebase SDK.
```

Any help on this will be very appreciate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just released a patch version `0.61.1` for `MLKitCommon` CocoaPod.  Please install the latest `GoogleMLKit` and let us know if the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** July 15, 2020: Run `pod update`.

As pointed out by @Dong Chen, the issue is now fixed with `MLKitCommon` version 0.61.1.

---

This looks like a bug in the `MLKitCommon` pod. It is depending on a version 3.x of `GoogleDataTransport` and Firebase is several versions later.  The CocoaPods installation finds a compatible version of Firebase which is several months old.

Comment: yeah I believe the issue is on `GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport` since this still on 1.x and Firebase, as you said, is already on 3.x. That's causing the conflict.

Comment: Source: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/d0a8d430ef6697894f32107df984552f3ab1a3f4/Specs/c/c/6/MLKitCommon/0.61.0/MLKitCommon.podspec.json

Comment: Actually just the `GoogleDataTransport` pod version. `GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport`  is no longer used as it has been combined into `GoogleDataTransport`